# Nginx proxy_pass for relative paths

Tags: nginx, rewrite, reverse-proxy

I currently have an Nginx configured this way.

`location /ui/ {
        proxy_pass http://ui:8888/;
      }`

This works but I'm having problems with retrieving some resources from the service, for example, some css styles that are referenced with /styles/style.css giving a 404. How can I tell the browser that the base URL is /ui/ and not / ? Is it possible?

I've also tested this configuration with no luck:

`location /ui/ {
        proxy_pass http://ui:8888/;
        proxy_redirect http://$host/ /ui/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
      }`

Comment: Nope. Use subdomain instead

Comment: I think I can't use subdomains, because I need to access this service from another one with a relative path.

Comment: You should be able to do this using ngx_http_sub_module, like this: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32542282/how-do-i-rewrite-urls-in-a-proxy-response-in-nginx